# In Minecraft why do mobs get stuck in the ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I spawn a lot of mobs some of them get shoved into the ground and act like they are in a hole.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Why the down votes?  I have long wondered this as well.

Comment: This is because of a bug. Bug is because of a programmer's error. No one except the developer can say any more to you. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: @OrcJMR - That's not a good reason to downvote.

Comment: Everyone has a right to downvote whatever they like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug, and is still unresolved in the most recent release (1.7.2). There are a lot of player theories on what "triggers" it (stairs, ladders, trap doors, etc.) but no official consensus on what causes it, and as of right now, no fix for it. Other than manually "digging out" the mob. (https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-119)